# What is the ARMv7 with Neon equivalent of vmovd/vmovq?

Tags: assembly, simd, avx, neon, armv7

What are the ARMv7 with NEON equivalents to vmovd/vmovq listed below?

```
// copies the 32bit register to the dest vector and zeroes the upper
vmovd xmmY, edx
// copies the 64bit register to the dest vector and zeroes the upper 
vmovq xmmY, rdx

// copies the lower 32bits from the source vector to the dest vector and zeros the upper
vmovd xmmY, xmmX
// copies the lower 64bits from the source vector to the dest vector and zeros the upper
vmovq xmmY, xmmX
```

Comment: Funnily enough, it seems you want `VMOV`. Consult the instruction set reference for details.

Comment: I used godbolt first to see if the compiler would do it automatically when I gave it vectors and no matter which way I tried with armv7-a+simd among others, it was always trying to push the values one at a time whereas on the 64bit version, it properly gave me fmov the first time.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/1c11bP

Comment: Thank you! I was using gcc before and couldn't get it to output anything useful.

Comment: @Jester I don't think `vmov` does the trick.  OP asked the same question yesterday in `##asm` and I was unable to find a single instruction to perform this task.  It appears that a multi-instruction sequence might be needed.